# oracle data in InfoPath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, bcs

We have a InfoPath form on which wants to show real time data from Oracle database. E.g. Employee name in a drop down list in InfoPath form from employee table in oracle.

Don't want to populate employee data in external list rather want real time data directly from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom WCF service to host in SharePoint which can then pull the list from your Oracle DB and then populate the drop down list on Form Load Rule.

To access Oracle data using .Net:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm

How to write a custom WCF service:

http://blog.sharepointbits.com/2010/04/custom-wcf-services-in-sharepoint-2010_17.html

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.de/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible.infopath is designed to be used with sharepoint .so data can be submitted to list/library.I dont know whether building a custom web service would be helpful.